# chilkat error 425 Unable to build data connection TSL session of data connection not resumed

Tags: c++, ftp, chilkat

Hi I am trying to copy a file via FTP using chilkat, but I got the error " error 425 Unable to build data connection TSL session of data connection not resumed". It works with filezilla client just fine. Here is the code

```
    if (!CkGlob.UnlockBundle(BUNDLE_CHILKAT))
    {
      W_WARNING("error while activating Chilkat");
      return;
    }
    cSincFTP.ClearSessionLog();
    if(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].UsaProxy)
    {
      cSincFTP.put_ProxyHostname(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].szServer);
      cSincFTP.put_ProxyPort    (sParam.sFTP[nFTP].unPortaFireWall);
      cSincFTP.put_ProxyUsername(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].szUserName);
      cSincFTP.put_ProxyPassword(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].szSenha);
      //if((nProxyMethod=cSincFTP.DetermineProxyMethod())<=0) return(FALSE);
      cSincFTP.put_ProxyMethod(nProxyMethod);
    }
    cSincFTP.put_Hostname(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].szServer);
    cSincFTP.put_Username(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].szUserName);
    cSincFTP.put_Password(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].szSenha);
    cSincFTP.put_Passive((sParam.sFTP[nFTP].UsaPassiveMode?true:false));
    cSincFTP.put_Port(sParam.sFTP[nFTP].unPortaFTP);

    //Establish an AUTH TLS secure channel after connection on the standard FTP port 21.
    cSincFTP.put_AuthTls((sParam.sFTP[nFTP].unPortaFTP==990?false:true));
    //The Ssl property is for establishing an implicit SSL connection on port 990.
    cSincFTP.put_Ssl((sParam.sFTP[nFTP].unPortaFTP==990?true:false));
    for(;;)
    {
      if(cSincFTP.Connect()!=true)
      {
        auto razao = cSincFTP.get_ConnectFailReason();
        if (razao == 201)
        {
          cSincFTP.put_AuthTls(false);
          cSincFTP.put_AuthSsl(false);
          cSincFTP.put_Ssl(false);
          W_MSG("Not possible to use (TLS/SSL)");
          continue;
        }
        SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW));
        W_WARNING("Not possible to connect to the FTP server");
        return;
      }
      if(cSincFTP.get_AuthTls()||cSincFTP.get_AuthSsl()||cSincFTP.get_Ssl())
      {
        cSincFTP.ClearControlChannel();
        CkString CkHost;
        cSincFTP.get_Hostname(CkHost);

        //use the EPSV command instead of PASV for passive mode data transfers
        cSincFTP.put_UseEpsv(false);
        //PassiveUseHostAddr property tells the FTP client to discard the IP address part of the PASV response
        //and replace it with the IP address of the already-established control connection
        cSincFTP.put_PassiveUseHostAddr(true);
      }
      cSincFTP.put_KeepSessionLog(true);
      break;
    };
    cSincFTP.DeleteRemoteFile(szRemoteFile1);
    cSincFTP.DeleteRemoteFile(szRemoteFile2);
    cSincFTP.RemoveRemoteDir(szRemoteDir);
    cSincFTP.SetTypeBinary();
    auto res = cSincFTP.ClearControlChannel(); 
    if(cSincFTP.PutFile(szRemoteFile1,szRemoteFile1)!=true)
    {
      //IN here I got the error
    }
```

The file szRemoteFile1 is created however is empty. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Chilkat should fix the problem.  You're likely using an older version of Chilkat?

Comment: thanks.. that kind of error drive anybody crazy